# total user/active device install count not update in android developer console

Tags: android, console, count, zero

I have just publish my first app on GooglePlay about 12 hours ago...

I found that inside my Developer Console, the total user installs/active device count keep showing **0** after many install and a few rating/review from my friends.
The *30 days install history graph* also doesn't show up.

Anyone know is there anything I do wrong in publishing setting?

My app is: Timer Master
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pro.learning.testtimer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInByby5sZWFybmluZy50ZXN0dGltZXIiXQ..

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

it updates everyday 12 am PST (Pacific time)

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628

Comment: Officially yes, but I've found it can be regularly up to 6 hours late (and sometimes much more, like today; 20 hours late and counting)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wait 48 hours for apps which are not free. This is because of the refundable timeframe. Google waits before displaying to the developer in the event a refund is granted.

If the app is free, give it around 12 hours and it will update.